# Inserting content into the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that jQuery has the [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function which allows you to place content at the end of an element, but is there a way to insert it at the top or somewhere in between, with a location specified as a parameter?

This is how I've been doing it:

```
var newContent = "<div>Top</div>";
var content = $('#myDiv').html();
$('#myDiv').html(newContent + content);
```

I am wondering if there is a function that allows you to insert at the top of an element and/or if there is a function that allows you to insert content into a certain location, where you might pass in a child-element and the content would be placed right after/before that element, even though it might not be at the top or the bottom of the element.

Thanks and any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/), [before](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the following methods:

```
append(); // Appends to the element
prepend(); // prepends to the element
insertAfter(); // inserts a sibling after the element
insertBefore(); // inserts a sibling before the element
```

In your case you want to utilize `prepend()`.

```
var newContent = "<div>Top</div>";
$('#myDiv').prepend(newContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep! [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) and [before](http://api.jquery.com/before/) both let you insert before an element, using slightly different syntax depending on your preference.

`insertBefore`:

```
$("<div>Top</div>" ).insertBefore( "#myDiv" );
```

`before`:

```
$( "#myDiv" ).before( "<div>Top</div>" );
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has built in functions like [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) and [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/).

Example:

```
$('#your-element').after('<span>I am after that element with the ID #your-element</span>');
```

Also there are functions like `prepend()` to add elements as child but at the beginning of the parent, and `append()` to add it after the  parent's last child.

Example:

```
$('#your-element').prepend('<span>Im the first element in the #your-element element.</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `.prepend()`:

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('#myDiv').prepend(newContent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/)  function to prepend element inside `<selector>`

```
var newContent = "<div>Top</div>";
$(newContent).prependTo('#myDiv')
```